# How to add robots.txt in kohana?

Tags: .htaccess, kohana, robots.txt

I am new in kohana.
I am trying to set robots.txt file for search engine indexing.
I have this `.htaccess`

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /mysite/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [L]
```

I want to set this into `robots.txt` file:

```
https://mysite.com/contact-us
```

I have this type of `robots.txt` file in my root:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /contact-us/

Sitemap: https://mysite.com/sitemap.xml
```

But when I search in mysite in google I show this page.
**mysite.com** is just for example.
How can I hide this from indexing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The line `Disallow: /contact-us/` will block all URLs whose paths **start** with `/contact-us/`.

Thus it blocks, for example, `http://example.com/contact-us/`, but not `http://example.com/contact-us` (without the trailing slash).

So if you want to block `http://example.com/contact-us`, you should use:

```
Disallow: /contact-us
```